# Convert nested aray into group of objects: Javacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am having an object that has the following structure

```js
const arr = [
  {field: "f1", values: [{ count:1, value: "a"}, { count:2, value: "b"}] },
  {field: "f2", values: [{ count:3, value: "c"}, { count:4, value: "d"}] }
];
```

Output should look like

```js
output = {
  f1: { name: "f1", selected: [] },
  f2: { name: "f2", selected: [] }
}
```

Basically the value in `field` should be key in the new object, also its name should have the same value with empty selected array

Code that I tried.

```js
arr.map(item => {
    return { item: { name: item, selected: [] } }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
    { field: "f1", values: [{ count: 1, value: "a" }, { count: 2, value: "b" }] },
    { field: "f2", values: [{ count: 3, value: "c" }, { count: 4, value: "d" }] }
]

const output = arr.reduce((p, { field }) => {
    p[field] = { name: field, selected: [] };
    return p;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Array.reduce()` to do it

```js
let arr = [
    { field: "f1", values: [{ count: 1, value: "a" }, { count: 2, value: "b" }] },
    { field: "f2", values: [{ count: 3, value: "c" }, { count: 4, value: "d" }] }
]

let result = arr.reduce((a,v) => {
  let obj = {'name':v.field, 'selected': []}
  a[v.field] = obj 
  return a
},{})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.map()` to get the field name, and a `.reduce()` to compose the object from the field name:

```js
const input = [
  {field: "f1", values: [{ count:1, value: "a"}, { count:2, value: "b"}] },
  {field: "f2", values: [{ count:3, value: "c"}, { count:4, value: "d"}] }
];

let result = input.map(obj => obj.field).reduce((acc, name) => {
  acc[name] = { name: name, selected: [] };
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is already an array. No  need for a map

Comment: @mplungjan: Point taken. I added it for clarity, e.g. two steps: 1. extract field name, 2. create the property in the object

Answer (score 0):

Reduce saves an assignment but makes the code more complex to read.

forEach is better in this case

```js
const obj = {}; 
arr.forEach(({field}) => obj[field] = {name:field, selected:[]})

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
  {field: "f1", values: [{ count:1, value: "a"}, { count:2, value: "b"}]},
  {field: "f2", values: [{ count:3, value: "c"}, { count:4, value: "d"}]}
];
</script>
```

Alternative is creating an object from entries generated from a map.
Still shorter than a reduce, but getting closer to it.
Still easier to see we end up with an object than go looking for the reduce initialiser.

```js
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map(({field}) => [field, {name:field, selected:[]}])
);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [
  {field: "f1", values: [{ count:1, value: "a"}, { count:2, value: "b"}]},
  {field: "f2", values: [{ count:3, value: "c"}, { count:4, value: "d"}]}
];
</script>
```

Comment: Hmmm,I do  not see the complex when using `Array.reduce()`,can you help me to understand it ? thanks

Comment: `let result = arr.reduce((a,v) => { a[v.field] = {'name':v.field, 'selected': []}; return a; },{})` compared to 
`let result = {}; arr.forEach(v => obj[v.field] = {name:v.field, selected:[]})` is certainly simpler and easier to read, and we know up front the code creates an object. I love reduce, but it is not a universal tool